How to denormalize data in EF Core with Azure Cosmos Db?
As shown in this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/model-partition-example#v2-introducing-denormalization-to-optimize-read-queries
I need to denormalize an entity which also lives in another container:
public class Post
{
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
       public List<Hashtag> Hashtags { get; set; } = new List<Hashtag>();
}

public class Comment
{
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int PostId { get; set; }
       public string Text { get; set; } = null!;
       public List<Hashtag> Hashtags { get; set; } = new List<Hashtag>();
}

public class Hashtag
{
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
       public int Puntuation { get; set; }
}

So for faster queries I need to embed the Hashtag in the Comment and in the Post (this is just an example, not a real use case), but the hashtag lives in it's own container.
I know this it's not possible in EF Core due to I'll se an error like this:

The type 'Hashtag' cannot be marked as owned because a non-owned entity type with the same name already exists.

Any solution?
I've tried doing something like this:
builder.Entity<Post>().ToContainer("Post");
builder.Entity<Post>().OwnsMany(p => p.Hashtags);

builder.Entity<Comment>().ToContainer("Post");
builder.Entity<Comment>().OwnsMany(p => p.Hashtags);

builder.Entity<Hashtag>().ToContainer("Hashtag");



How to denormalize data in EF Core with Azure Cosmos Db?

Below is an example on how to denormalize the data in EF Core with Azure Cosmos DB. In this the Order entity contains nested entities Customer and OrderDetail. In the OnModelCreating method, entity configurations are set up to define how the entities are stored in Cosmos DB. OwnsOne and OwnsMany methods are used to specify ownership and configure nested entities. Sample data is seeded into the database using the HasData method. This data includes an Order entity along with its associated Customer and OrderDetail entities. Denormalization is performed by grouping relevant data into a single document or container as shown in the below output.
public class Order
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public string Id { get; set; }  
    public string OrderId { get; set; } 
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class ECommerceContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(
            "<url>",
"<primary_key>",
            databaseName: "firstDb");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .OwnsOne(o => o.Customer, customer =>
            {
                customer.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("OrderId");
                customer.Property<string>("CustomerId").IsRequired();
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsMany(o => o.OrderDetails, od =>
        {
            od.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("OrderId");
            od.Property<string>("Id").IsRequired(); 
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .ToContainer("Orders")
            .HasPartitionKey(o => o.id);

        // Seeding the Order entity
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasData(new Order
        {
            id = "order1",
            OrderDate = DateTime.UtcNow
        });

        // Seeding related Customer entity
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsOne(o => o.Customer).HasData(new
        {
            OrderId = "order1",
            CustomerId = "customer1",
            Name = "Pavan Sai",
            Email = "pavan.sai@email.com"
        });

        // Seeding related OrderDetail entities
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsMany(o => o.OrderDetails).HasData(
            new
            {
                Id = "orderdetail1",
                OrderId = "order1",
                ProductId = "product1",
                ProductName = "Product 1",
                ProductPrice = 10.0m,
                Quantity = 2
            },
            new
            {
                Id = "orderdetail2",
                OrderId = "order1",
                ProductId = "product2",
                ProductName = "Product 2",
                ProductPrice = 20.0m,
                Quantity = 1
            }
        );
    }
}

Output:
{
    "Id": "order1",
    "OrderDate": "2024-06-10T00:00:00Z", 
    "Customer": {
        "CustomerId": "customer1",
        "Name": "Pavan Sai",
        "Email": "pavan.sai@email.com"
    },
    "OrderDetails": [
        {
            "Id": "orderdetail1",
            "ProductId": "product1",
            "ProductName": "Product 1",
            "ProductPrice": 10.0,
            "Quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "Id": "orderdetail2",
            "ProductId": "product2",
            "ProductName": "Product 2",
            "ProductPrice": 20.0,
            "Quantity": 1
        }
    ]
}


In that case, you are embedding, not denormalizing your data. A denormalize case would be if you have the customers in another container and you duplicate the customer into the order for faster queries to the order container avoiding querying multiple containers and partitions.

Code has been edited with the required changes. Could you please check and verify once.
